# JQuery continously sending AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am trying to use `Jquery` Ajax request to implement AutoComplete feature. I am using `ElasticSearch` in the backend.

Here's my `autocomplete.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Autocomplete using Elasticsearch "> 
        <title>Elasticsearch Autocomplete</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .container{
        width:90%;
        margin:5em auto;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="search" onfocus="setFocus(1)" onblur="setFocus(0)">
            </div>
            <div id="results"></div>
        </div><!-- /container -->
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var focus=0;
    var results='';
    function setFocus(n){
        focus=n;
        getSuggest();
    }
    function getSuggest(){
        var search=$('#search');
        var text=search.val();
        var feed ='{"suggest" : {"text" : "'+text+'","completion" : {"field" : "suggest"}}}';
        $.post( "http://localhost:9200/songs/_suggest?pretty", feed, function( data ) {     
            //console.log (data['suggest'][0]['options']["0"]['text']);
            $.each(data['suggest'][0]['options'],
                function(index, value){
                    results+=value.text;
                    results+='<br/>';
                }
                );
            $('#results').html(results);
            results='';
            if (focus==1) setTimeout(function(){getSuggest()}, 300);
        });
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

It's working fine also. Here's the output:

[image]

But I have two issues:

1. Ajax keep sending request to backend even if I'm not typing anything else. I just type **br** and can see the two results. It should not send any request after that. Here's the output from Firebug:

[image]

2. I would like to select the element in autocomplete dropdown. e.g. below

[image]

Feel Free to ask if you have any question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an infinite, recursive loop in your code. The line

```
if (focus==1) setTimeout(function(){getSuggest()}, 300);
```

calls `getSuggest()` recursively, every 300 milliseconds, unless the value of `focus` is changed to be unequal to 1. The value of `focus` is not changed in `getSuggest()`, therefore the recursive loop may continue limitlessly unless the value of `focus` is changed externally.

**Edit**:

To call the `getSuggest` function whenever the search field's text is changed you can use the jQuery `.on()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").on("change click keyup keypress input paste", getSuggest);
});
```

It's a little excessive to use all of those events in `on`, and you may or may not want to include them all, but this would call `getSuggest` whenever the search field's input value is changed.

Comment: But if I remove this line then it will send only 1 request to the server. Any recommended way to overcome this?

Comment: Thanks Andrew! It was sending three requests every time if I changed the text. I have reduce the event to `change click input` and it's working fine. Also can you help me how to select one of the result and fill in input box?

Answer (score 0):

When the function setFocus is called, the function getSuggest is called, which at the end call's itself if focus equals 1:

```
if (focus==1) setTimeout(function(){getSuggest()}, 300);
```

The problem is that focus isn't set to 0 (or anything different than 1), so getSuggets keeps calling itself time after time.